# Html not showing results from Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm running into an issue with HTML not displaying the console.log output from Typescript. I'm new to programming and would appreciate some assistance.

My Typescript below:

```
class Grocery {
    constructor(name:string, quantity: number, price: number ){
        console.log("buy vegetable" + name, " with quantity" + quantity, " for price" + price)
    }
    color(){
        console.log("Green")
    }

}

let basil = new Grocery("Cabbage", 3, 5)
basil = new Grocery("basil", 4, 10)
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Typescript Grocery</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="grocery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you,
Yen

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not outputting anything because you're not calling any methods. So if you did this:

```
basil.color();
```

Then your code would run. But you're not calling `color()`, so it won't run in the code in your question.